# How to use es6 every to return boolean value on nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, boolean

Trying to use `every` javascript method if any `indexID` have combination of `firstFillCounter` and `refillCounter` it should return `retvalue` true its throwing `undefined` any idea what would be better approach ?

main.ts

```
  private arrayMatch(data) {
        const isCombined = this.validateOrder(data);
        if (isCombined) {
            return Promise.reject(this.errorHandler(request, "First and Refill cant be combined"));
        }
        return isCombined;
    }

    private validateOrder(rxDetails) {
        let isCombined: boolean = false;
         isCombined = rxDetails.every( (o: any) => {
            this.isCombinedFirstandRefill(o.rxInfos);
      });

      return isCombined;
  }

  private isCombinedFirstandRefill(rxInfos) {
      let retVlaue: boolean = false;
      let firstFillCounter: number = 0;
      let refillCounter: number = 0;
      for (const rx of rxInfos) {
          if (rx.firstFillIndicator === "Y" && rx.acceptDigitalFirstFill === "Y") {
              firstFillCounter++;
          } else {
            refillCounter++;
          }
      }
      if (refillCounter > 1 && firstFillCounter > 1) {
          retVlaue = true;
          return retVlaue;
      }
    return retVlaue;
  }
```

this should return true and consider invalid request.

```
const data = [{
    indexID: 1,
    rxInfos: [{
        firstFillIndicator: "Y",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "Y",
        rxNumber: "1512"
      },
      {
        firstFillIndicator: "Y",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "N",
        rxNumber: "16021"

      }
    ]
  }]
```

this is valid it should return false from `isCombinedFirstandRefill`

```
  const data1 = [{
    indexID: 2,
    rxInfos: [{
        firstFillIndicator: "Y",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "N",
        rxNumber: "1512"
      },
      {
        firstFillIndicator: "N",
        acceptDigitalFirstFill: "N",
        rxNumber: "16021"

      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: The function passed to `every` needs to return a Boolean value. Right now, the function being passed calls `this.isCombinedFirstandRefill(o.rxInfos);` but does not return the result. Either prepend `return` or remove the curly brackets.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Can you please give me an example problem you are referring to

Comment: An example of the problem I am referring to is in the code in the question. In the `validateOrder` function, the following code is present: `isCombined = rxDetails.every((o: any) => { this.isCombinedFirstandRefill(o.rxInfos); });` The function `(o: any) => { this.isCombinedFirstandRefill(o.rxInfos); }` returns no value (`undefined`) to the `every` function. Hence your error. You can either add `return` to it; `(o: any) => { return this.isCombinedFirstandRefill(o.rxInfos); }` or remove the brackets: `(o: any) => this.isCombinedFirstandRefill(o.rxInfos);` Either will return a value to `every`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey i added `return` it throws error rxInfos is not itteriateable however it is an array